# Merging dataframes on row.names: column is put in capital letter

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

With the following code:

```
d1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3))
d1$id <- c("A","B","C")
d2 <- data.frame(b=c(4,5,6))
d2$id <- c("A","B","C")
d3 <- merge(d1, d2, by="id")
print(d3)
```

The dataframe `d3` will contain a column "id".

With the following code:

```
d1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3))
rownames(d1) <- c("A","B","C")
d2 <- data.frame(b=c(4,5,6))
rownames(d2) <- c("A","B","C")
d3 <- merge(d1, d2, by="row.names")
d3
```

The dataframe `d3` will contain a column "Row.names".

Why R put that in title case? Why in the second example the name is changed to have the first letter in capitals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the source code of `merge.data.frame`, it is creating the `Row.names` in `cbind` and the `0` based condition is if we specified the `by` for `0` i.e. for merging by row (as mentioned in the documentation part -below)

```
...

else {
        if (any(by.x == 0L)) {
            x <- cbind(Row.names = I(row.names(x)), x) ####
            by.x <- by.x + 1L
        }
        if (any(by.y == 0L)) {
            y <- cbind(Row.names = I(row.names(y)), y) ####
            by.y <- by.y + 1L
        }
        
...
```

The documentation doesn't say much about this except that

> the name "row.names" or the number 0 specifies the row names. If specified by name it must correspond uniquely to a named column in the input.